# Does subharmonic barrier force the domain to be contained in analytic domain?

Tags: general-topology, plane-geometry, potential-theory

Let $D \subset \Bbb R^2$ be a domain, and suppose that there is a subharmonic barrier at some point $\zeta \in \partial D$, i.e. a function $w$ negative on $D$, tending to $0$ on $\zeta$ and with negative partial limits at all other points of $\partial D$.

Does that force $D$ to be included in some domain with analytic boundary?

I read a book by Tsuji that seems to rely on this fact in a corollary, but this is not clear to me. It is enough if one proves that $D^c$ has a nonempty interior, as it implies the above claim. The main problem is that I lack necessary properties for the existence of a barrier; I only know sufficient conditions. (such as the existence of a continuum in the complement starting at the point of the barrier.)

replacing `analytic` by `piecewise-smooth` is also enough for the aim of Tsuji, though he seems to indicate it even for the analytic case.

Comment: Let $D$ be the complement of the graph of [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function); then $D$ isn't contained in any domain with analytic boundary, unless we consider $\mathbb R^2$ such a domain. But it admits barriers at every point, since the complement is a nontrivial continuum. You may have misunderstood the author there.